# Save *.csv without spaces and double quote

Tags: python, csv

This is my line

`csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')`

And this is my output:

`O;4;State[1,1,2]; ;`
`O;3;INFO; ;`

I do not want to have spaces. How to save file wihout spaces and double quote?

---

Source file (new_list):

```
['O', '3', 'INFO', '', '', ';', "']"]
['V', '4', 'FillLevel', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'INT0', '64", '2002', 'CPUA.DB1610.0,I,64;RW', 'RW', '0', "0']"]
['O', '4', 'State[1,1,1]', '', '', ';', "']"]
['V', '5', 'Occupied', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'X128.0", 'B', 'CPUA.DB1610.128,X0;RW', 'RW', '0', "0']"]
['V', '5', 'Locked', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'X128.1", 'B', 'CPUA.DB1610.128,X1;RW', 'RW', '0', "0']"]
['V', '5', 'ErrDriveRoll', "S7:[CPUA]DB1610', 'X128.2", 'B', 'CPUA.DB1610.128,X2;RW', 'RW', '0', "0']"]
```

Save csv:

```
with open(source_file, "w", newline='') as f_output:
            csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')
            for r in range(len(new_list)):
                csv_output.writerow(new_list[r][0:3] + new_list[r][5:6])
```

Comment: Can you give a complete code example , please? With the data you are using to write the csv

Comment: use the .strip() command

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: @ArdaNalbant How to apply this to my example ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually think that this is happening because you've specified an `escapechar=' '` argument in your `csv.writer()` call here:

```
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')
```

[The documentation for `escapechar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar) says:

> A one-character string used by the writer to escape the delimiter if
>   quoting is set to QUOTE_NONE and the quotechar if doublequote is
>   False. On reading, the escapechar removes any special meaning from the
>   following character. It defaults to None, which disables escaping.

And since you've used `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` it has preceded semicolons with a space like you've specified. Your third list that you've pasted in your question has a `;` at its 5th index.

I still don't think that this will completely solve your problem though because I can't tell if you're trying to read from a file that has its data structured as rows of lists. It also looks like you might be writing to your your source file, which could have unintended consequences.

Comment: I tried also your code line, and not solved my problem.
Now I have in each line spacebar:
`O;3;INFO; ;`
`V;4;FillLevel;CPUA.DB1610.0,I,64 ;RW`
`O;4;State[1,1,1]; ;`
`V;5;Occupied;CPUA.DB1610.128,X0 ;RW`

Maybe will be better to open this file, remove spacebar and save again ? But I think than I will have the same problem ?

Comment: That line is copy and pasted from your original question.